# Is it necessary to keep Node modules and Grunt file in same directory?

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, gruntjs

I am new to Grunt & I am working on project in which I need to have two angular apps but I want to keep node modules & bower components at common location so that, I don't have to do installation at two places. I created combined generic `package.json` & `bower.json` files & installed them. Now I need to update my respective Grunt files to use node modules from that common location.
**Is it possible to serve node modules from any other location than gruntfile to run grunt task.**

Ex: I want both **client-app-one** & **client-app-two** run their individual grunt task from common node modules.

`/project-root-dir
    /project-root-dir/client-app
    /project-root-dir/client-app-one/Gruntfile.js
    /project-root-dir/client-app-two/Gruntfile.js
    /project-root-dir/package.json
    /project-root-dir/node_modules/
    /project-root-dir/bower.json
    /project-root-dir/bower_componenets/`

Comment: Might not answer your question, but IMO it is not a good idea to have 2 separate apps have the same dependencies. These files are suited to be associated with one unique project, not multiple.

Comment: The issue has been discussed [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/696) since... well... three years ago...

Comment: @IronGeek Thanks I checked discussion & found solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding solution to my problem as discussed [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/696). Thanks @IronGeek for sharing link in comment.
I made changes in my grunt file as follows to achieve above explained scenario:

**Gruntfile.js**

`var cwd = process.cwd();
    process.chdir('../');
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    process.chdir(cwd);`